# How ro store rowids in order to delete them after corresponding child records are deleted

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, parent-child

I would like to delete certain rows that i collect with the following select:

```
DELETE from REMINDER 
where exists 
(
SELECT r.rowid
FROM reminder r
inner join reminder_users u on u.reminder_id = r.id
inner join device d on d.id = (regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', '')) and d.NEXT_TEST_DATE_INTERNAL <> u.deadline
inner join device_test t on t.id = d.NEXT_TEST_INT_ID
where u.receipt = 0 and t.TEST_INTERNAL_EXTERNAL = 0 and r.NAME like '%Interne%' and r.NAME not like '%Externe%' and u.DEADLINE > sysdate
);
```

The problem is, that there is a table 'reminder_users' that contains child records for the parent-table 'Reminder'. So I have to delete the child records first with the following statement:

```
DELETE from REMINDER_USERS
where exists
(
SELECT u.ROWID
from reminder_users u
inner join reminder r on r.id = u.reminder_id
inner join device d on d.id = (regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', '')) and d.NEXT_TEST_DATE_INTERNAL <> u.deadline
inner join device_test t on t.id = d.NEXT_TEST_INT_ID
where u.receipt = 0 and t.TEST_INTERNAL_EXTERNAL = 0 and r.NAME like '%Interne%' and r.NAME not like '%Externe%' and u.DEADLINE > sysdate
);
```

When I perform the second operation, the first statement returns obviously zero rows, because I deleted the child records. This is why I am looking for a way to store the rowids from the first operation, delete the child records afterwards and finally delete the previously stored data from the table 'REMINDER'.

Do I have to use a CURSOR here? (Note: If the querys return rows, there will always be at least 2 rows affected). I tried to declare a variable that stores the rows, but then I get an 'ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows' error...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `REMINDER_USERS` is a child table of `REMINDER` then there should be a foreign key tying the two tables together. If the foreign key has a `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause then the `REMINDER_USERS` table will be automatically deleted when the `REMINDER` is deleted.

Comment: I dont want to use an `ON DELETE CASCADE`, because the users are allowed to perform deletes in the `REMINDER` table. If they do so, and there is a row in `REMINDER_USERS` table (pointing to a different user) that shall not be deleted, the deletion is prevented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely have a foreign key constraint between `reminder` and `reminder_users`. You shouldn't be *able* to delete out of `reminder` if there is a child record in `reminder_users`. That's just basic database referential integrity.

If that foreign key is defined as `on delete cascade`, you're done. Deleting out of `reminder` will delete the dependent records in `reminder_users`.

Assuming you can't do that, one thing you can do is grab the ids to delete first, then delete them. You need to create a schema-level `type`:

```
create type id_tt as table of number;

declare
    l_reminder_ids id_tt;
begin
    select r.id 
      bulk collect into l_reminder_ids
      from reminder r
     inner join reminder_users u on u.reminder_id = r.id
     inner join device d 
             on d.id = (regexp_replace(r.origin_values, '[^0-9]', '')) 
            and d.NEXT_TEST_DATE_INTERNAL <> u.deadline
     inner join device_test t on t.id = d.NEXT_TEST_INT_ID
     where u.receipt = 0 
       and t.TEST_INTERNAL_EXTERNAL = 0 
       and r.NAME like '%Interne%' 
       and r.NAME not like '%Externe%' 
       and u.DEADLINE > sysdate
       for update;

    delete from reminder_users where reminder_id member of l_reminder_ids;

    delete from reminders where id member of l_reminder_ids;
end;
```

The `for update` clause is there to prevent some other session from coming in and messing with those rows while you're deleting from reminder_users. (Hmm, now that I think about it, that may not be necessary here.) This assumes the number of rows you are trying to delete is "reasonable." If you're trying to delete 20 million rows, this may not have very good performance.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is of course a foreign key constraint between the tables `REMINDER` and `REMINDER_USERS`. Your assumption is correct, I dont want to use an `ON DELETE CASCADE` because of the given uncertainties. Actually your solution really looks pretty good to me, I will give it a try!

Comment: When I try to use your code in a PL/SQL script in SQL Developer i get the error "PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements". 
I changed `type id_tt is table of reminders.id%type;` into `type id_tt is table of reminder.id%type;`, but I think there is still a problem with the pl/sql table and the records cannot be collected into it?

Comment: Oops, I forgot local types like that only work inside packages, not anonymous blocks. You need to create a schema level `type`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! The number of rows is "reasonable", that means about up to ten rows per day. But "per day" means also, that I want do schedule this script as a job running nigtly. When I run the script fo a second time, I get an ora-error "name is already used by an existing object". This is understandable. Is it okay to adjust the first line to `create or replace type id_tt as table of number;` ? Or do I also have to drop the type at the end?
Note: I also had to add a single `/` at line 2 to get the code working without compilation errors...

Comment: Yes, the type is a schema object, like a table, so it only needs to be created once.

Comment: Sorry for annoying you, but I have one more question: When I try to run the code as a job (as a PL/SQL block) it fails with error code 01002 "fetch out of sequence". When I run the code as a script, it runs without an error. Do you have a clue, what the problem is?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. It looks like it has something to do with placing a commit. Does your actual code have a commit somewhere?

Comment: The problem was that I added a `dbms_output.put_line` line in the code. After deleting it, the code worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If "on delete cascade" as suggested by @EJEgyed is available to you then that is the way to go. But many DBAs (including myself) do not as a rule allow that. The side effects are just considered too dangerous. You may not know exactly what is being deleted and Oracle does not tell you, it just deletes away. If that is your case you have a couple options.

1. Just repeat the sub-query. That will accomplish what you
   need.
2. Run a script using "returning ... bulk collect' in the 1st delete,
   the "forall ... delete" for the second. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3baf7bded4772d32870211fe15ba766c)).

```
declare 
    type rem_list_t is table of reminder_users.rem_id%type;
    ren_list rem_list_t; 
begin 
    delete 
      from reminder_users 
     where rem_id in ( select rem_id 
                         from reminders 
                        where rem_id in  
                              (select to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(1,200)))
                                             from  dual connect by level <= 4           
                              )      
                          and message not like '%Event #6' )
     returning rem_id  
         bulk collect 
         into ren_list;
         
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Rows deleted from reminder_users:' || to_char(sql%rowcount));  
         
    forall ru in 1 .. ren_list.count
       delete 
         from reminders 
         where rem_id = ren_list(ru); 
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Rows deleted from reminders:' || to_char(sql%rowcount));          

end ;
```

*A word of warning*. Your current query are malformed. They will either delete 0 rows because nothing meets the where criteria is the subselect or it will delete **All ROWS** because at least 1 row satisfies the where criteria. The EXIST predicate evaluates true it 1 or more rows satisfy the criteria, but it is true for EVERY ROW in the outer criteria. Demo, also contains a sample.  I do not have your table definitions nor sample data, so the demo is built on simple table/query, but keep the same structure of your SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, i dont want to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` because of the uncertainties you mentioned.

Comment: ...and also thank you for your warning! I see that you eliminated the danger of deleting all rows in your solution. So i will try a `BULK COLLECT`